# Angular show/hide on parent component based on child component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a parent component with the following template:

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

How can I show or hide the `app-sidebar` or `app-footer` component based on the component routing through the router outlet? I have a boolean `showSidebar` I'd like to use, with it's value set to true or false on each child component.

```
<app-sidebar *ngIf=showSidebar></app-sidebar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app routes add a data property.

```js
  { path: 'no-sidebar', component: NoSidebarComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { showSidebar: false } },
```

and subscribe to the router events in the parent component like this

```js
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
      const routeData = event.state.root.firstChild.data;

      if (routeData) {
        this.showSidebar = routeData.showSidebar === false ? false : true
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of direct component to component communication, you could use a service to share the show/hide flag and inject the service in the enclosing component as well as the the ones routed to.

For example child components' onInit, set a flag in the shared service instance. The parent component containing the router outlet, would read that flag and use it along with an *ngIf to show or hide parts of the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subject variable, whenever you want to hide or show that time emits value of variable and subscribe to that variable in sidebar and footbar